# Puppet : Warning: Only one file can be applied per run. Skipping

Tags: puppet

I'm installing an application called "Bag Of Holding" using the puppet script provided on [github](https://github.com/ribeiroit/boh-puppet). I installed successfully then needed to make a change to the site.pp and init.pp file but when I tried to recompile using (puppet apply ), I got the warning message

> Warning: Only one file can be applied per run.  Skipping /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp

And no other activity on the screen. I was unable to access my application after that. After a day of troubleshooting I gave up and started from scratch - re-install my CentOS, puppet, and all the folder directories were in place, but as soon I run "puppet apply", I got the same Warning as previously and I have since not been able to access the application.

How could the compilation fail for a newly installed operating system with application being installed freshly? Is it not possible to run puppet site.pp file more than once? Is there anything hard coded to the server after the first run and can no longer accept additional compilation? Both site.pp and init.pp file are on the github I posted above. I'm running masterless puppet configuration set up.

site.pp code:

```
# adding boh module to the node

node 'boh.domain' {
    class { 'boh':
        python_version => 3,
        environment => 'dev',
        language => 'pt-br',
        debug => 'True',
        create_superuser => 'true',
        pkg_checksum => '86b0164f7fd6c5e4aa43c8f056f08cea',
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `puppet apply` command you are executing?

Answer (score 0):

Question no longer relevant. I found the fix by ensuring appropriate syntax was being used...puppet apply -
-- modulepath=
Thanks